# SQL query to get the data not including latest versions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm working in SQL Server 2012. I have a table which contains below 2 columns

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
     border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
   <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
     <th>Version</th> 
   </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
     <td>0</td> 
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>1</td>
     <td>1</td> 
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>1</td>
     <td>2</td> 
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>1</td>
     <td>3</td> 
   </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
     <td>0</td> 
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>2</td>
     <td>1</td> 
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>2</td>
     <td>2</td> 
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>3</td>
     <td>0</td> 
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>3</td>
     <td>1</td> 
   </tr>
</table>
```

I want to get only the id which are having more than 2 versions and not include the latest 2 versions(meaning for Id 1 there are 4 versions among that i need to extract only latest 2 versions(3,2)).

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
     border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
   <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
     <th>Version</th> 
   </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
     <td>0</td> 
   </tr>
  <tr><td>1</td>
  <td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td>
  <td>0</td></tr>
</table>
```

How to write the query?  I have tried the below query                     select * from bitest where version not in
(
select version from bitest where version in(
SELECT Max(version)
FROM bitest
GROUP BY id
HAVING Max(version)>=  2
)) 
and id in
(
select distinct id from bitest where version in(
SELECT Max(version)
FROM bitest
GROUP BY id
HAVING Max(version)>=  2
))                                                                              please correct the query to get the desired result

Comment: I have tried the below query,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get only the ids which have more than 2 versions,try this:

```
SELECT id,COUNT(version) FROM tt GROUP BY id HAVING COUNT(version)>2
```

Comment: thank you..can you please help to get the versions prior to latest 2 versions

Comment: can you please explain more what you want?

Comment: I have got the query using Rank()

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [ID] TINYINT
   ,[Version] TINYINT
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([ID], [Version])
VALUES (1,0)
      ,(1,1)
      ,(1,2)
      ,(1,3)
      ,(2,0)
      ,(2,1)
      ,(2,2)
      ,(3,0)
      ,(3,1);

SELECT [ID]
      ,MIN([Version]) AS [Version]
FROM @DataSource
GROUP BY [ID]
HAVING COUNT([Version]) > 2;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If i am understood correct, you are looking for this :-

```
Set Nocount On;

Declare @test Table
(
     Id             Int
    ,Version        Int
)

Insert Into @test(Id,Version) Values
 (1,0) 
,(1,1) 
,(1,2) 
,(1,3) 
,(2,0) 
,(2,1) 
,(2,2) 
,(3,0) 
,(3,1) 


Select  *
From    @test As t
Where   t.Version Not In (  Select  Top 2
                                    t.Version
                            From    @test As t
                            Order By t.Version Desc
                         )

---- Ids which having more than 2 versions BUT NOT latest 2 Versions.
Select   t.Id
From    @test As t
Where   t.Version Not In (  Select  Top 2
                                    t.Version
                            From    @test As t
                            Order By t.Version Desc
                         )
Group By t.Id
Having Count(t.Version) > 2
```